# Flexslider corrupted resolution

Tags: jquery, html, flexslider

I have a problem with flexslider.I just put the basic codes which is provided in http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

My jquery code :

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });
});

My html code:

<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="img/a.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="img/b.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="img/c.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

However the resolution of my images is corrupted. If I show only one image there is no problem but if it is more than one, the resolution of images get worse. Can you solve this basic problem please?

Comment: are all your images the same dimensions?

Comment: yes,and if I use all pictures same,for instance  all a.jpg,it still does not work but if I use only one it is perfect

Comment: Hm, have you changed any of the default CSS that accompanies the slider?

Comment: I did not change anything.

Comment: Okay, so you're making this in a clean environment, i.e. not a site with any other style sheets or script that might be conflicting with it? 

Have you looked to see if you're getting a Console error? 

Also, would it be at all possible for you to demonstrate this on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) perhaps?